# ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.3 change the value of a field to lowercase in InfoTemplate

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, infowindow

Is there a way to change the case of a text field in an InfoTemplate using ArcGIS JavaScript 3.3?

Let's say I am bringing in a feature layer, and it is a requirement that I ensure that the field value for {$gaugelid} is lowercase, as I am constructing a URL to preview that particular Gauge ID's Hydro-graph in the Info template.

The formatting for the Hydro-Graph URL is: *https://water.weather.gov/resources/hydrographs/Lowercase(${gaugelid})*_hg.png)

If it's not possible when constructing the InfoTemplate, is there a way to define that I want those values as lowercase in the definitionExpression or when I define the outFields?

```
var HydroURL = 'https://water.weather.gov/resources/hydrographs/${gaugelid}_hg.png';
var iframeHydro = "<iframe src='"+HydroURL+"' style='width:100%;height = '400';'></iframe>";
console.log(iframeHydro);
var content = "<b>Location: </b>${location}<br><a href='${url}'><b>Status: </b>${status}</a><br><b>Observation:</b>${observed}${units}<br><b>Observation Time: </b>${obstime}<br>"+iframeHydro;
var gaugetemplate = new InfoTemplate("${gaugelid}", content);

var currentGaugeData_lyr = new FeatureLayer(
    "https://idpgis.ncep.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NWS_Observations/ahps_riv_gauges/MapServer/0",
    {
      definitionExpression: "state = 'TX'",
      outFields: ["*"],
      infoTemplate: gaugetemplate
    }
  );
var gaugeSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ask for the data to be returned lowercase, but you can display it lowercase once you have the data on the client.

There is a sample that shows how to use custom functions, and a help page that talks more about this:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_formatInfoWindow.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_formatinfowindow.html